# Initialization of a hash_map in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, hashmap

I've created a map in C++ to store directions for different chess pieces using the following structure:

```
map<Piece, vector<tuple<Offset, Type, Color>>> PIECE_DIRECTIONS;
```

When attempting to add elements to the map, such as:

```
PIECE_DIRECTIONS[Pawn].push_back(tuple<Up, Push, Red>);
PIECE_DIRECTIONS[Soldier].push_back(tuple<Up, Push, Red>);
```

I'm getting the error message 'This declaration has no storage class or type specifier.' How can I resolve this issue? Are there alternative ways to achieve the same goal, such as using vectors or arrays instead of a map?

Is accessing elements in a map faster compared to arrays and vectors? In my specific case, the speed of accessing elements is crucial, and methods like insertions and deletions are not a significant consideration.

Comment: A few things, do NOT use tuple for this but a struct of your own. `std::tuple` is intended to be used for template programming

Comment: Something like map<Piece, vector<Direction>> ?

Comment: Try `std::make_tuple(Up, Push, Red)`

Comment: Can you post a piece of code we can compile to see the same error? See [mcve].

Comment: @Ariana `std::map` does not use hashing.  The "hash map" in C++ is `std::unordered_map`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get something like this (I did not add the vector yet, but that adds on level of extra {} for initialization). I just wanted to give you an idea. ;)

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

enum class Piece
{
    Pawn,
    Bishop,
    Rook
};

enum class Color
{
    Black,
    White
};

struct Direction
{
    int horizontal;
    int vertical;
};

struct Movement
{
    Color color;
    Direction direction;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<Piece,Movement> moves{
        { Piece::Pawn, // <- key of your map, e.g. a Piece enum value
         { 
            Color::White,   // First member of Movement, e.g. Color enum value
            {0,1}           // Second member of Movement, Direction {0 horizontal, 1 vertical)
         }
        },
        { Piece::Bishop, { Color::Black, {8,8} } }
    };

    return 0;
}
```